# Global variables cleared after submit action Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I submit in vue js:

```
 <form v-on:submit="updateEmployee">
```

and in the method updateEmployee when this call is invoked:

```
  router.push({
     path: '/'
  });
```

the global variables values gets cleared after routing.

```
var employees = [

];
```

Why does this happen in Vue js even though no page refresh has taken place ?

Comment: are you sure no page refresh occurs? can you try v-on:submit.prevent or @submit.prevent ? Where do you store your global variables? how do you access them. Provide more code please

Comment: Why there is the angular tag in the question ?

Comment: @FrankProvost why page refresh would take place ? The js framework internally routes and places the template. Global variable is employees at the top. Its value is assigned in different template/component.

Comment: the page refresh could take place because of the submit. "The js framework internally routes and places the template" => Well good for you, but if you don't provide more code we will not be able to help you. The variables will be to find a solution. It's wild guessing. The definition of var employees is not helping at all. This could be anywhere.

Comment: Ok. Got your point. Just read about v-on:submit and .prevent variant. Just one question, isn't it better to use .prevent as its better for Single page application. Why do we need reload ? Thats what JS framework like vue, angular is all about.

Comment: You do not need to reload. That's the point, and in order to avoid your browser to reload, you need to `prevent` the event `submit` from being fired further than your updateEmployee function.

Comment: You are preventing default browser action, and default browser action is "reload" after form is submitted.If you add `.prevent` modifier on submit event, page won't "reload".

Comment: Yeah I was using e.preventDefault() before learning about .prevent variant in vue js.

Comment: vue isn't a SPA framework at all. You are talking about the Vue Router plugin which isn't part of the Vue Core

Comment: @FrankProvost But vue js is a js framework mostly used for building SPA's ? Isn't it ?

Comment: Not at all - why do you think so - as said the core has not special functionality for builiding SPA's. It's a "progressive framework for building user interfaces" (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/). You can use vue in any other framework you can user other frameworks routers within vue or use vue in  basic not single page applications just to privode data binding.

Comment: I think form submit could trigger a refresh. May I know where you declared the global variable? P.S: You could simply write `router.push('/')` instead of `router.push({path: '/'})`